# How do i change my app's bundle ID?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I'm making a pro version of my app and a free version, whereas i just had the free version, which is already on the app store. So how do i change my bundle ID for the pro version of my app. Do i have to do something inside of xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a new target.  In Xcode, just go to File --> New Target.

This will create a separate target with a new main and info.plist.  In there you can specify the app bundle ID for your pro version.  Then in the target dropdown (the one you use to specify which to device to debug on) you can specify which target you want to debug and eventually build/submit for.

This creates a clean separation of your Pro and Lite builds, while being able to share the code you have already created.  For each of your files, you'll need to specify which (or both) targets they need to belong to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works; however, might I suggest you use in-app purchase to activate the paid features?  That way existing users of your software will get an upgrade notification from Apple (that they should install the new version).  I imagine most users interested in paying for your paid features are the same ones who are currently using your free version.

Comment: But then you have to live with all the low ratings of drive-by-downloaders. `I'm an idiot, I didn't read the description, and I don't know what it does, but this app does not look useful. *`